# samples on Garageband on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, garageband, ios

Is it possible to import samples into the iPhone version of Garageband?

I have see that its possible to do this on the iPad & mac version but I am not sure if I can do it on the iPhone.

Comment: Do you mean "samples" as in something you can play in a virtual musical instrument, or do you mean any audio recording that you want to place in an audio track for mixing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can import audio files into the iPhone version of Garageband.

[Here are the instructions from Apple.](http://help.apple.com/garageband/iphone/1.2/index.html#chsab9d208e)